# Blazor webassembly .NET Core hosted migrate to .NET 8 without CascadingAuthenticationState component

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor, openid-connect, .net-8.0

I have some .NET Core hosted web assembly project that uses OIDC auth on external company server, configured as:

```cs
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(opt =>
{
    opt.ProviderOptions.Authority = "https://xx.xx.pl/auth/realms/xx";
    opt.ProviderOptions.ClientId = "xxxx";
    opt.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("email");
    opt.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = "code";
});
```

I wanted it like this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/70-80?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#update-a-blazor-webassembly-app

In .NET 8, I don't use the `CascadingAuthenticationState` component, so if I add:

```cs
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
```

nothing changes / redirects as it should / nothing breaks.

But when I remove the `<CascadingAuthenticationState>` component, when I run, I see not authorized - ok

Redirects to external logon page as should, and I can login, after which it goes back to 'my page'

I see "Authentication completing login..." as I should, but instead of redirecting to previous page, it fails with:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]   
Unhandled exception rendering component: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.  
System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNextRare()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CascadingValueSource`1.<>c__DisplayClass10_0[[System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].<NotifyChangedAsync>b__0()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.NullDispatcher.InvokeAsync(Action workItem)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CascadingValueSource`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].NotifyChangedAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CascadingValueSource`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].NotifyChangedAsync(Task`1 newValue)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.CascadingAuthenticationStateServiceCollectionExtensions.AuthenticationStateCascadingValueSource.HandleAuthenticationStateChanged(Task`1 newAuthStateTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationStateProvider.NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task`1 task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService`3[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteUserAccount, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.OidcProviderOptions, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].UpdateUser(Task`1 task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService`3.<UpdateUserOnSuccess>d__30[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteUserAccount, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.OidcProviderOptions, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService`3.<CompleteSignInAsync>d__21[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteUserAccount, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.OidcProviderOptions, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticatorViewCore`1.<ProcessLogInCallback>d__86[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticatorViewCore`1.<OnParametersSetAsync>d__84[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

adding

```
builder.Services.AddOptions();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks and regards

Comment: Same here, did you manage to sort it?

Comment: nope i left it as it was for now but strange